# Importing csv files and merging in a loop based on file name in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I have a folder of about 75 CSVs, some are for 2 of the same station, and some are stand alone.

Is there a way to loop through the folder, pull out two CSVs that have the same first 4 characters and export back out as one, merged CSV? In the loop below? All are same structure.

**Here are five sample file names (in the folder "Folder")**

```
> files
"13_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv"
"13_2016_10-01~2017-06-30.csv"
"1222_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv"
"1222_2016_10-01~2017-06-30.csv"
"1114_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv"
```

**Here is the code thus far to read in each file and export:**

```
z <- NULL
files <- dir("Folder")

for (file in files) {
  x <- read.csv(file.path("Folder", file), as.is=T, skip=12)

write.csv(x, paste(file)), row.names=F, col.names=F)
}
```

**Using this example, I'd want to end up with this list of files:**

```
> files
"13_2016-2017.csv"
"1222_2016-2017.csv"
"1114_2016-2017.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a regex match solution to iterate through file prefix sets for read/write csv operation:

```
# OP's POSTED EXAMPLE
files <- c("13_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv",
           "13_2016_10-01~2017-06-30.csv",
           "1222_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv",
           "1222_2016_10-01~2017-06-30.csv",
           "1114_2016_01-01~2016-09-30.csv")

# GENERALIZED FOR ALL CSVs IN WORKING DIR
# files <- list.files(path="/path/to/csv/folder", pattern="\\.csv")         

m <- regexpr("^.*_", files)    
file_prefix <- unique(regmatches(files, m))     # VECTOR OF UNIQUE PREFIX MATCHES
file_prefix
# [1] "13_2016_"   "1222_2016_" "1114_2016_"

# NAMED LIST OF ROW-BINDED DATAFRAMES
dfList <- sapply(file_prefix, function(p){
                dfs <- lapply(list.files(path="/path/to/csv/folder", 
                                         pattern=p, full.names=TRUE), function(f) {
                              setNames(read.csv(f), c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3"))
                       })                                  
                do.call(rbind, dfs)   
          }, simplify=FALSE)

# OUTPUT CSV FILES NAMED WITH PREFIX AND '2016-2017' SUFFIX
out <- mapply(function(d,n) write.csv(d, file=paste0(n,"2016-2017.csv"), row.names=FALSE), 
              dfList, names(dfList), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help - I am getting this error during the `out` function: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '1041*2016-2017.csv': Invalid argument

Comment: Interesting. Why is asterisk coming through? That is invalid char for files/dirs on Windows machines. What does your *file_prefix* vector output? Does your *dfList* contain dfs?

Comment: file_prefix vector output is: "1041", "1051", "109_" etc... I ran it again and it all seems to go through, export, etc now... without asterisk. But, when I look at the dfList, it just has NULL values, though it lists the appropriate # of files I would want... didn't seem to pull in CSV data

Comment: Filenames do not have any underscores? This solution expects it like your posted data.

Comment: Ah, yes. Files will not match exactly. They will match by the first 4 characters, not the full file name. So only the first 4 characters are pulled out of each name.

Comment: `file_prefix <- paste0(unique(str_sub(files,1,4)))`

Comment: Since this answer uses no outside package, consider base R's `substr`: `file_prefix <- unique(substr(files, 1, 4))` in place of the regex match.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I run through the dfList and now get this error: Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  first five rows are empty: giving up. (the error says it's giving up... I am not!)

Comment: I ran into same issue. Make sure you set working directory to location of csv files with `setwd()` or use the *path* arg in `list.files()` pointing to csv location.

Comment: the files are all listed correctly, exactly from the folder they are in. But they are not being pulled into that dfList... is there a way in the `dfs` line to `read.csv` from those exact files? Do I need to add an additional parameter?

Comment: Then, you are not using `setwd()`. Add the *full.names=TRUE* arg in `list.files()` inside the `sapply` so `read.csv()` picks up absolute path of csv. See my edited answer.

Comment: Getting closer, I think. New error:  Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names

Comment: One more caveat: these CSVs are assumed to be exact same structure (same column number and names). Else, the rowbind does not work. Consider dplyr's `bind_rows(dfs)` over base R's `do.call(rbind, dfs)` as former will add cols that do not match.

Comment: its REALLY close. the `bind_rows(df)` works, but it is creating 3 new columns to the right of the existing 3, instead of just inserting the rows at the bottom of the existing rows. Can I merge the columns regardless of the name of them? There are exactly 3 in each but named differently!

Comment: In row bind operations, *colnames* must match in order to append to each other. If you know the names in advance, go ahead and rename the columns. See edit using `setNames`. Adjust as needed.

Comment: setNames!!! That's it. Thanks for your updated code and continuous help solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test my code without having your data so I'd treat my answer closer to pseudo code but I think this should work:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
files <- list.files() #List all the files
FileGroups <- paste0(unique(str_sub(files,1,4)),"*") #find the file groups and apend a '*' for regex in next code chunk

for (i in 1:length(FileGroups)){
  df <- list.files(pattern=FileGroups[i])%>% # find all files in one group
    lappy(read_csv()) %>% #read in
    bind_rows() #bind together
  write.csv(df,paste0(FileGroups[i],"_2016-2017.csv")) #output

}
```

You will probably need to play around with this but the idea is to first find all the different patterns, then to load all csvs that match that pattern and bind them. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242065/trying-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-in-r) for the rowbind code. Also, you say 4 digit code, but by your example, you might have 2 digit codes, I'd use str_split to find the groups if that was the case. Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I like this approach, and I appreciate you putting the code into a loop. I'm getting an error when I run through it, however:  Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection