# Merging csv files in R

Tags: r, rbind

I have around 5000 csv files of small sizes. each one has min 4 columns and maximum 7 columns. I want to merge them all either on single spreadsheet or different spreadsheets in one work book. I've referred [Trying to merge multiple csv files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242065/trying-to-merge-multiple-csv-files-in-r) at instance. 1st answer seemed to work but console gave me error massage as follows:

> Error: Column `V3` can't be converted from character to numeric In
>   addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the
>   first 50)

The thing that df is default function in R. So, i assigned value as `a<- list.files(.........)`
Where am I going wrong. Thanks for the Help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in some cases `V3` column is interpreted as character while in others it is interpreted as numeric (`readr::read_csv` tries a guess of your datatype to speed up import).

So, you can try the following

```r
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

df <- list.files(path="yourpath", full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  lapply(read_csv,  col_types = cols( .default = col_character())) ) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

You will import all columns as characters there, at the cost of performance (and the possible need to change column types later)

The equivalent `data.table` implementation (should be faster) is :

```r
library(data.table)

df <- lapply(list.files(path="yourpath", full.names = TRUE), fread)
df <- rbindlist(df, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ive applied both solutions. in both the cases it showed the same error that "Cannot allocate the vector of size 1.3mb.". Do you have any solution for that and thank you for help.

Comment: That's an out-of-memory problem. Reading all columns as character is far more memory demanding than only reading some of them with this type. Automatic solutions are hard to give. Since you have at most 7 columns, you can set the types manually (`colClasses` if you use `fread`, changing some columns in argument `cols` for `readr::read_csv`). If the problem persist, I would not go through 5000 files once but do that for some hundreds of files at a time and then combine all results afterwards